# How can I set required field filter Date field in magento2 grid

Tags: magento2, grid

How can I set required field in filter Date field in magento2 grid

**Interval** : This is required field. Admin can NOT click “Apply Filters” without selecting values in at least 1 among 2 fields.
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Interval : This is required field. Admin can NOT click “Apply Filters” without selecting values in at least 1 among 2 fields.